# Find Laurent series expansion of $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}, |z|>2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find Laurent series expansion of $\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$, $|z|>2$.

Using the The Binomial Theorem: $\pm z(z-1)^{1/2}(z-2)^{1/2} = \pm z[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-1)^{k}z^k][\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-2)^{k}z^k]$.

I have a problem how multiply these two sums.

The answer in the book: $c_n$ = $\binom{1/2}{k}$
+ $2\binom{1/2}{k-1}\binom{1/2}{1}$ + $2^2\binom{1/2}{k-2}\binom{1/2}{2}$ + … + $2^n\binom{1/2}{k}$ and  expansion is $\pm [c_0z-c_1+\frac{c_2}{z}-\frac{c_3}{z^2}+...]$

Could someone, please, help to get the right answer?

I think Cauchy product of the series can help to find coeffitients.

Comment: @Maam: I corrected it, type error

Comment: Metso, look at [Cauchy product of two power series]<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series>

Comment: @Did the domain of the square-root is outside the cut from 1 to 2 so it behaves in the domain of the question.

Comment: I don't think this function is holomorphic on this set.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri on the other hand, I think DougM was right.

Comment: Right about what? I'm not sure this question makes sense.

Comment: Does the book skirt around the definition of the complex logarithm? Traditionally, Laurent series are defined only for holomorphic functions in generalized annuli $($that is, we may have $r=0$ or $R=\infty)$. However, the complex square root is defined in terms of the complex logarithm, and the complex logarithm in turn cannot be continuously defined on any open set that contains a curve looping around the origin.

Comment: It is the square-root.  There are two possible values.  If you go on a loop around the origin, the quadratic increases phase by $4\pi$, so the square-root increases phase by $2\pi$.  So the choice of square-root remains consistent, and it is well defined on $|z|>2$.

Comment: @Empy2 You are correct, I guess, it suffices to choose one particular value of the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

   

The idea was correct:

$z(z-1)^{1/2}(z-2)^{1/2} =\pm z\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{z})}\sqrt{(1-\frac{2}{z})}$, 
then using the The Binomial Theorem:

$\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{z})} = [\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-1)^{k}z^{-k}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}\binom{1/2}{k}z^{-k}$ and
$\sqrt{(1-\frac{2}{z})} = [\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}(-2)^{k}z^{-k}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}2^k\binom{1/2}{k}z^{-k}$

Now we have : $\pm z[\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}\binom{1/2}{k}z^{-k}][\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}2^k\binom{1/2}{k}z^{-k}]$

Using Cauchy product: $[\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^n * \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^n] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^n$,

and $c_0 = a_0b_0, c_1 = a_1b_0 + a_0b_1  $ etc

$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}b_k $.

Then the coeff. $c_n  =  \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{1/2}{n-k}(-1)^k2^k\binom{1/2}{k} = (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n2^{k}\binom{1/2}{n-k}\binom{1/2}{k}$.

The Laurent  expansion: $\pm[c_0z - c_1 + \frac{c_2}{z^2} - ... ]$